# How to replace/update data being save in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have save a json data in core data. The problem for my app is whenever I called api again, the data that being called and save is appending into new row in core data. what I want is whenever I called the api again, the data from before is being replace or update. How can I achieve this? I read it I can use **NSBatchUpdateRequest** but I still don't understand how to implemented.

This is my code

```
ApiSession.shared.send(request) { (response) in
        if let err = response.error {
            print("Failed to get youtube data:", err)
            return
        }

        guard let results = response.value else { return }
        self.nextPageToken = results.nextPageToken
        results.items.forEach({ (result) in
            let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistenceContainer.viewContext
            if let video = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Video", into: context) as? Video {
                video.videoTitle = result.snippet.title
                video.videoId = result.id.videoID
            }

            let request: NSFetchRequest<Video> = Video.fetchRequest()

            do {
                try context.save()
                let videos = try context.fetch(request)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.videos = videos
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let saveErr {
                print("Failed to save video:", saveErr)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: You would need to retrieve the existing object (if any) with the specific `videoID` and  update its values rather than inserting a new object

Comment: @Paulw11 do you mean I only have to fetch the json data even though the object is NSManageObject?

Comment: No, you have to try and fetch the Core Data object with the corresponding ID that you got from the JSON.  If there is an existing Core Data object, update it (or do nothing).  If there is no existing Core Data object, create a new one

Comment: @Paulw11 can you show me in a code?

Comment: If you get full data for API call, you could wipe the entire table in a single operation and then insert object again. May be faster than search and update/add for every item.

Comment: @thomasgotzsche I already have wipe function, but it's not the one I looking for. my app more like when you select a certain row in tableview, it present a new controller and have the navigation name. example if I select setting in row, it push to new controller with navigation name setting. so my api is called based on passed in the name I select, and the problem is the data is appending. but thank your solution .

Comment: ok, so if you just want to replace the data, then first do a search for the entity by some kind of unique key. If you find it, re-populate the entity with data from API call. If not, create new item and populate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update an existing record you have to fetch it by given ID and check if the record exists.

If it exists, update it.
If not, create a new one.

```
ApiSession.shared.send(request) { response in
    if let err = response.error {
        print("Failed to get youtube data:", err)
        return
    }

    guard let results = response.value else { return }
    self.nextPageToken = results.nextPageToken
    let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistenceContainer.viewContext
    results.items.forEach({ result in
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Video> = Video.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "videoId == %@", result.id.videoID) // if videoID is Int change the placeholder to `%ld`
        do {
            let videos = try context.fetch(request)
            if let video = videos.first {
                video.videoTitle = result.snippet.title
                self.videos.append(video)
            } else {
                let video = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Video", into: context) as! Video
                video.videoTitle = result.snippet.title
                video.videoId = result.id.videoID
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to fetch video:", error)
        }
    })
    do {
       try context.save()
    } catch {
       print("Failed to save video:", error)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "Video")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "videoId = %@", result.id.videoID)
    var videoList: [NSManagedObject] = []
    var video: Video
    do {
        videoList = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }
    catch {
        print("error executing fetch request: \(error)")
    }

    if videoList.count > 0 {
        video = videoList[0] as! Video
    } else {
        video = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Video", into: context) as? Video
        video.videoId = result.id.videoID
    }

    if let v = video {
        v.videoTitle = result.snippet.title
    }
```

Comment: I have an error say "value of type NSManageObject has no member of videoTitle" under let video = videoList[0]. I already have the videoTitle in entity but why it show error?

Comment: what if you change to
let video = videoList[0] as! Video

Comment: yes, you need to add the insert logic into the error part or change the logic a bit to test for that. I will update the code to reflect the full logic.

Comment: @thomasgotzsche thank you for your contribution, I already have an answer from vadian. but I appreciate your help. thank you again :)